# Java 8 Stream, anyMatch

Tags: java-8, java-stream

```
boolean isSuccess = aMap.entrySet().stream().anyMatch(entry -> {
                AKey aKey= entry.getKey();
                BValue bValue = bMap.get(aKey);
                if (bValue == null) {
                    return false;
                }

                AValue aValue = entry.getValue();
                if (compareDetail(aValue, bValue)) {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }
    );
```

this code always only loop one time, how can i loop all elements then return true when two if blocks false?

Comment: you want `all` elements to match your `Predicate`?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what the output should be. Do you require all the map entries to pass this Predicate? You can use `allMatch` instead of `anyMatch`.

Comment: @Eugene yep, if two Predicates are false, and i want to continue to loop, and return true on last time loop

Comment: @Eran i had tried `allMatch`, but still loop one time when 2 predicates false.

Comment: So you want `noneMatch`?

Comment: maybe i need a way how to debug `allMatch`......one by one, each element..maybe `allMatch` has been done all the loop, but i only see one time in debug.

Comment: @HavenLin well, why you need loop all elements when using `anyMatch` ? what purpose you want to loop all elements for debug?

Comment: You should stop reasoning about what it does and start considering what result you actually want. `allMatch` implies that *all* elements must match, which is impossible when one element doesn’t match, hence, it doesn’t need to process all elements, when it encountered one nonmatching element. Just like `a && b` will not evaluate `b` when `a` is already `false`.

Comment: @holi-java i have changed `allMatch`, because i want to verify my code logic,so i need to debug all elements for all case.

Comment: @HavenLin `allMatch` does not meet your need, that @Holger have proposed. you may need `reduce`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to try `allMatch` instead.

Comment: @HavenLin, well, can you please share your code for more details? I mean `compareDetail` method and `AKey`, `AValue` objects

Comment: it is too long, i can send screenshot to you.